# Use "vscode.open" command from TreeDataProvider

Tags: vscode-extensions

How do you open a file from a custom tree view item when authoring a vscode extension? Here's a sample tree view item:

```js
import { URI } from 'vscode-uri';
import { TreeDataProvider, ProviderResult, TreeItem } from 'vscode';

export class CustomTreeProvider implements TreeDataProvider<TreeItem>{

    public getChildren(element?: TreeItem): ProviderResult<TreeItem[]> {
        if (!element) {
            return [{
                id: 'some-unique-id',
                label: 'some-unique-label',
                command: {
                    command: 'vscode.open',
                    title: 'Open',
                    arguments: [URI.file('path/to/file']
                }
            }];
        }
    }

}
```

However, whenever I click on that tree view item, it fails with this message in the console:

> [renderer7] [error] Running the contributed command: 'vscode.open' failed. Illegal argument 'resource' - Resource to open: Error: Running the contributed command: 'vscode.open' failed. Illegal argument 'resource' - Resource to open

I have a workaround where I can register my own custom command to open the file, but I'd rather use the built-in "vscode.open" command if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `vscode.open` command doesn't like the `Uri` generated by the `vscode-uri` package. Use `vscode.Uri` instead.

```
import { TreeDataProvider, ProviderResult, TreeItem, Uri } from 'vscode';

export class CustomTreeProvider implements TreeDataProvider<TreeItem>{

    public getChildren(element?: TreeItem): ProviderResult<TreeItem[]> {
        if (!element) {
            return [{
                id: 'some-unique-id',
                label: 'some-unique-label',
                command: {
                    command: 'vscode.open',
                    title: 'Open',
                    arguments: [Uri.file('path/to/file']
                }
            }];
        }
    }

}
```