# In vs-code extensions, how to pass parameters into commands in viewsWelcome.contents

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm playing with vs code extension development, and I'm trying to create a `viewsWelcome` element.

`content` accepts a string with markdown annotations, the following works as expected

```
"viewsWelcome": [
  {
    "view": "view-id",
    "contents": "[Clone Repository](command:git.clone)"
  }
]
```

However, when trying to replace `command:git.clone` with [`command:vscode.open`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) which accepts an uri as parameter, the parameter is not working.

```
"viewsWelcome": [
  {
    "view": "view-id",
    "contents": "[Open URL](command:vscode.open?[https://foobar.com])"
  }
]
```

I haven't found documents about the syntax, except for some examples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/codetour/blob/main/README.md#command-links), which is not working as well

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63792186/836330 for `Uri.file('path/to/file'` syntax or vscode.Uri.parse('https://example.com') : `vscode.Uri.parse('https://example.com')`

Comment: Did you try to set the `contents` property as follows: `"contents": "[Open URL](command:vscode.open?[\"https://foobar.com\"])"`? Please note the double qutotes I escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @ct_jdr thanks but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to generate the correct arguments string:

```js
const args = [ 
    vscode.Uri.parse("https://foobar.com") 
];

const encodedArgs = encodeURIComponent(
    JSON.stringify(args)
);
    
console.log(encodedArgs);
// %5B%7B%22%24mid%22%3A1%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22scheme%22%3A%22https%22%2C%22authority%22%3A%22foobar.com%22%7D%5D
```

Then add the encoded arguments to the `command:` URI:

```json
"viewsWelcome": [
  {
    "view": "view-id",
    "contents": "[Open URL](command:vscode.open?%5B%7B%22%24mid%22%3A1%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22scheme%22%3A%22https%22%2C%22authority%22%3A%22foobar.com%22%7D%5D)"
  }
]
```

As you can see it is not sufficient to just pass the URL as a plain string like you did. It has to be the JSON representation of a `vscode.Uri`.
Additionally, you have to properly URL-encode the resulting JSON before adding it to the `command:` URI.

Btw, it was the "command:git.stage" example in the [VS Code API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris) that got me on the right track.